# Two sets of labels in chemnum

Tags: chemnum

Is it possible to have two sets of labels for numbering compounds throughout the document? Currently I'm using `chemnum` to make labels like **1**, **2**, **3a** and so on. I want to introduce a new sequence of numbers, say, **TS1**, **TS2**... The only idea I have is to reset the counter right before I introduce new labels like this:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\cmpdinit[init-sub = true]{1,2,3.{a,b}}
\newcommand*{\cmpdTS}[1]{\cmpd[cmpd-prefix=\bfseries{TS},cmpd-space={}]{#1}}
\begin{document}
Here are two compounds: \cmpd{1} and \cmpd{2}.

\cmpdreset
Here are two transition states: \cmpdTS{TS1.a} and \cmpdTS{TS2}.

Which of these two transition states is involved in transformation of \cmpd{1} to \cmpd{2}?

What about \cmpd{3.a}? It is formed from \cmpd{2} via \cmpdTS{TS3.a}.
\end{document}
```

But it's a bad idea because in the output I get: "What about **3a**? It is formed from **2** via **TS4a**." instead of: "What about **3a**? It is formed from **2** via **TS3a**." because of the resetting the counter.

Comment: You're missing a dot in `\cmpdinit`. Change it to `\cmpdinit[init-sub = true]{1,2,3.{a,b}}`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake:-) Am I right that this method will work if I initiate all the labels for one sequence in, for example, preamble and then just reset the counter before I need to introduce a new sequence?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: The dot fixes the issue (in case that wasn't clear from my earlier comment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Original answer**

The line

```
\cmpdinit[init-sub = true]{1,2,3{a,b}}
```

initates three labels: `1`, `2` and `3{a,b}`. Every further label used in the text will still be created (and write a warning in the log that it hasn't been initiated). Thus the numbering goes:

```
Here are two compounds: \cmpd{1} and \cmpd{2}.% numbers 1 and 2

\cmpdreset% new numbers will start at 1 again
Here are two transition states: \cmpdTS{TS1.a} and \cmpdTS{TS2}.
% 1a and 2

Which of these two transition states is involved in transformation of \cmpd{1} to \cmpd{2}?
% 1 and 2 again

What about \cmpd{3.a}? It is formed from \cmpd{2} via \cmpdTS{TS3.a}
% `3' was never declared but gives `3' as this is the next number to be declared,
%`TS3' consequently gives `4`
```

So what you want is this:

```
\cmpdinit[init-sub = true]{1,2,3.{a,b}}
```

which initiates labels `1`, `2` and `3` and the sublabels `3.a` and `3.b`.

You could have seen this easier by using the option `init-strict` which will cause errors if an uninitiated label is used. My suggestion would be to do something like the following, i.e. declare every label in the preamble together with `init-strict`:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chemnum}
\cmpdsetup{init-strict,init-sub}% error if unititialized label is used

% regular labels
\cmpdinit{1,2,3.a}

% transition states
\newcommand*{\cmpdTS}[1]{\cmpd[cmpd-prefix=\textbf{TS},cmpd-space={}]{#1}}
\cmpdreset
\cmpdinit{TS1.a,TS2,TS3.a}

\begin{document}
Here are two compounds: \cmpd{1} and \cmpd{2}.

Here are two transition states: \cmpdTS{TS1.a} and \cmpdTS{TS2}.

Which of these two transition states is involved in transformation of \cmpd{1} to \cmpd{2}?

What about \cmpd{3.a}? It is formed from \cmpd{2} via \cmpdTS{TS3.a}.
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit 2014/03/14**

Since 2014/03/12 version 1.0 of `chemnum` is available. This this new release comes with a change in many ways I'd like to give the solution for the new version as well:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chemnum}[2014/03/12]
\setchemnum{init,log=verbose}

% regular labels
\initcmpd{1,2,3.a}

% transition states
\resetcmpd
\initcmpd[pre-label-code=\textbf{TS}]{TS1.a,TS2,TS3.a}

\begin{document}
Here are two compounds: \cmpd{1} and \cmpd{2}.

Here are two transition states: \cmpd{TS1.a} and \cmpd{TS2}.

Which of these two transition states is involved in transformation of \cmpd{1}
to \cmpd{2}?

What about \cmpd{3.a}? It is formed from \cmpd{2} via \cmpd{TS3.a}.
\end{document}
```

[image]