# Two different counters in chemnum package

Tags: counters, chemistry, chemnum

Is there any possibility to use two independent counters within the `chemnum` package? I would like to label (by replacing the tags in my .eps file) substances in reactions and steps in catalytic cycles with different styles. The former with simple numbers, and the latter with letters (A,B,C,...).

If I only change the style of numbering before replacing the tags, I don't get a new counter. So if I already showed the compounds 1,2,3 and now want to describe a step in a cycle, `chemnum` will replace the tag with D instead of the favoured (wanted!) A.

Comment: Does this question and its answers help?http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72946/two-sets-of-labels-in-chemnum

Comment: I found that solution but it looks like that I have to declare the compounds in the beginning. I would rather like to declare the labels while replacing the tags via \replacecmpd{...}. Otherwise it seems to me that I have to rearrange the order when changing the order of sections, during the review. And that would be a real pain in the ass...

Comment: `chemnum` only has one counter so if you don't want to declare the labels in the preamble (which I wouldn't want to do either) you probably have to reset the counter for the second set... I may be able to add something to `chemnum`, though. I'll have a look...

Comment: I'll than have to employ a well thought sublabel structure. Nevertheless, thanks for looking into it. The package overall is really nice, since one has not to worry about consistent numbering ;) Thanks so far